# Generic Request Param (runtime construction)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, generics, spring-4, http-request-parameters

My requests look like:

```
http://...
  ?type[A].size=14
  &type[B].query=test
```

My `@Controller` has a method which should accept those generic request params:

```
@RequestMapping(...)
public void test(MyModel m) {
   ...
}

public static class MyModel {
  Map<String, ?> type;
}
```

The problem is: `?` should be some class which is defined by the key of the `Map`.

This means: `key=A` should Map to class `A` and `key=B` should map to class `B`. According to the given request above: Class `A` will have a property `int size` and class `B` will have a property `String query`.

I just can't figure out, how I can tell Spring to use class `A` for key `A` and class `B` for key `B`.

(I know I could do it with `POST` and Jackson, but I'd like to solve this using a `GET` request).

Thanks for your help `:)`

Comment: What you are expecting can not be easily achieved. You would have to write your own custom implementation.

Comment: Isn't it even possible to use something like `Map<String, MyContainer>` where `MyContainer` simply accepts every possible key-value pair? **Btw:** `Map<String, Map<String, Object>>` doesn't work, this would only accept `?type[A][size]=14`, but not `?type[A].size=14`. With this `Map<String, Object>` I could use Apache's `BeanUtils.populate` to copy all those properties to my desired class.

Comment: First you must understand what Query String in a URL is. It is part of HTTP Protocol and multiple parameters consisting of only a single Key and a Value can be part of the Query String. Any complex structure you want to be passed must be handled in your controller code explicitly.

Comment: Of course I know what the query string is. The main "problem" with this is (for me): Jackson can do such things easily (using @JsonType), I thought: "Spring is broad and mighty and has a tool for (nearly) every use case, this must be in there". Every 6 month I find some missing feature in Spring `;)`, at least now I know that there will be no problems in the next half year `:)`. I think I'll just tell my frontend dev to change his code and use `?type[A][size]`. Thank you!